# Interpretation of coefficients in logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic

So I have weight (kg) as a predictor variable and FEV1 groups as binary outcome (<3L is 0 and >=3 is 1).

I've centered and standardised the weight variable so weight_centered = (weight-70)/20, reason being 70kg is close to the mean of the weight variable and β1 would correspond to change of 20kg in weight rather than 1kg.

From the parameter output generated in R I've come up with the equation $$\log(odds) = -1.293 +0.023\times weight$$

From what I understand, if you exponentiate -1.293, which is 0.275, it can be interpreted as odds of having FEV1 equal to or greater than 3L when weight is 70kg (correct?), but what would be the interpretation for β1?

Also, is my approach to centering and standardising the weight variable appropriate for logsitc regression or am I better off just leaving it as it is?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to CV.

0.0023 is the increase in the log odds for each unit increase in weight. You've made the units 20 kg. You should, in the output, also see the odds ratio, which is the multiplicative change in the odds for each unit increase in weight. This should be $e^{0.023} = 1.0023$. So, when weight increases by 20kg, the odds increases by a multiple of 1.0023.

Should you center and standardize?  Well, opinions vary. I am toward the "not usually" group, but others disagree. I would say that if the original units are meaningful (as they are here) then that's one reason not to standardize. And if the units are sensible (as they seem to be here) that's another reason. (By "sensible" I mean e.g. that you have measured the weight of adult humans in kg, not g). Also, while the meaning is the same, in this particular case, if you had left it as kg, then the odds ratio wouldn't have multiple 0's before the first significant figure. That makes it easier to read.